# autoreconf is failing to create configure from configure.ac

Tags: linux, autotools

I was trying to build xtables-addons from sf.net.

I have cloned xtables-addons git repo from SF. It has a "autogen.sh" to
create the configure script. ./autogen.sh is failing with following
message:

```
/usr/bin/m4:configure.ac:33: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `m4_if' ignored
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: autom4te failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

I'm not experienced in autotools, so i'm clueless about what's actually
going on there.

The autogen.sh contains the follwing:

```
#!/bin/bash

autoreconf -fi;
rm -Rf autom4te*.cache;
```

Why its failing? i have all the autotools.

EDIT:

```
[root@s1 xtables-addons]# /usr/bin/m4 --version
m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.13
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Rene' Seindal.
```

Comment: What does `/usr/bin/m4 --version` say?

Comment: updated question with m4 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [this bug report](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/8593). You can get the attached patch from there, or just go to line 32 in `configure.ac` and remove a superfluous close square bracket after `autodetect`. I.e. change this:

```
    [Path where to install Xtables extensions [[autodetect]]]]),
```

to this:

```
    [Path where to install Xtables extensions [[autodetect]]]),
```